# How to reference local version of a project in another Gradle project dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a Gradle project (say project A) that depends on another Gradle project (say B). Each project live in their own git repository. Sometimes when I have to make a non-trivial change across both projects, I will make the code changes in B and push to remote where our CI will pick it up and release it as a new version.

Then in project A, I will update the version for B with the new version number, then run `./gradlew generateLock saveLock` and then I will be able to use the new changes made in B to implement the feature in A.

I want to avoid having to push B to remote and release a new version before I can start using the new code in A. Ideally, I want to make change to B locally and have A reference the local version of the project. That way I can test both and test the whole feature before I push any code. How can I achieve that using Gradle. I am using Gradle 7.5?

I declare my dependency on B in A's `build.gradle` as `implementation 'com.something.project-b'`. Note that B might have a bunch of other library dependencies of its own declared in its own build.gradle which should still be transitively pulled when I want to use the local version of B in A.

Any pointers?

There is a local JAR option in Gradle but that will not pull all the transitive dependencies of B and I do not want to build a combined JAR of B and all its dependencies and use that since then I lose all dependency resolution benefits in case of conflicts.

Also note that B is an independent project and cannot simply be moved to Project A as a sub-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do any sort of local workstation hodgepodge.  All you need is the following:

1. Declare `mavenLocal()` as the first repository in the dependent project (you probably already have `mavenCentral()`.
2. Publish the dependency to Maven local repository using the task `.gradlew publishToMavenLocal`.

Now, your dependent project can use the latest code from the dependency.

Comment: If I was using explicit version number for project B in the build.gradle file of project A, then should I remove that version number? I wanted to me more explicit so that I KNOW that the local version is being used, how do I do that.

Comment: @SwarangaSarma You can keep the same version number, but delete the publication from your Maven local first. For example, for `group=com.asarkar.grpc`, `artifact=grpc-test`, and `version=1.2.2`, you'll delete `$HOME/.m2/repository/com/asarkar/grpc/grpc-test/1.2.2`. You can also choose a different version number, but that depends on how frequently you change the dependency. If you keep making changes, it's not practical to keep changing the version number.

Comment: I should add that the artifact is overwritten as expected, so, the above isn't really necessary. I simply provided you couple of options since you asked.

Answer (score 0):

in the project 'A'

settings.gradle

```
include ':prjB'
project (':prjB').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../relativePath')
```

build.gradle

```
def prjBExists = file('path-to-prjB').exists

dependencies {
...

   if (prjBExists) {
       implementation project(':prjB')
   } else {
      implementation 'g:a:v'
   }
}
```

PS - this referencing is under discussions as gradle-8 is expected to deprecate ...